# current_user no me da rails 5, Callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails

hola quiero que cuando se crea automaticamente guarde el nombre y email, cuando se ejecuta el Callbacks me sale el siguiente error, gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**reunion.rb**

```
class Reunion < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = 'reuniones'
   belongs_to :planta
   belongs_to :centro_costo
   belongs_to :producto
   self.table_name = 'reuniones' 

  before_create :guardaremailsolitante
   def guardaremailsolitante
    self.emailsoli = User.find(current_user.id).email
    self.nombresoli = User.find(current_user.id).name
   end

 end
```

Comment: El error se debe a que el _helper_ `current_user` no está disponible en los modelos (podrías agregarlo, pero no lo recomiendo). ¿Podrías mostrar tu modelo completo o darnos más contexto sobre la acción para poder recomendar opciones alternativas?

Comment: @Gerry hola ya lo organize, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Lo más sencillo (y en mi opinión la mejor opción) sería incluir la información de `current_user` como parte de los atributos (i.e. parámetros) que utilizas para crear el objeto `Reunion` en tu controlador y eliminar el *callback* del modelo; por ejemplo:

**reunion.rb**:

```
class Reunion < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = 'reuniones'

  belongs_to :planta
  belongs_to :centro_costo
  belongs_to :producto
end
```

**reuniones_controller.rb**:

```
class ReunionesController < ApplicationController
  # más métodos

  def create
    reunion = Reunion.new(reunion_params)

    if reunion.save
      # acciones para guardado exitoso
    else
      # acciones en caso de error
    end
  end

  private
  def reunion_params
    params.require(:reunion)
          .permit(:planta_id, :centro_costo_id, :producto_id)
          .merge(emailsoli: current_user.email, nombresoli: current_user.name)
  end
end
```

---

Adicionalmente (si la lógica de tu aplicación lo permite) podrías evaluar modificar el modelo `Reunion` para que, en lugar de tener los atributos `emailsoli` y `nombresoli`, tengas una relación con `User`, evitando registrar dos veces el mail y nombre del usuario.

Considerando este cambio, el código anterior se vería así:

**reunion.rb**:

```
class Reunion < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = 'reuniones'

  belongs_to :planta
  belongs_to :centro_costo
  belongs_to :producto
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**user.rb**:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord   
  has_many :reuniones

  # más relaciones, validaciones, métodos, etc,
end
```

**reuniones_controller.rb**:

```
class ReunionController < ApplicationController
  # más métodos

  def create
    reunion = Reunion.new(reunion_params)

    if reunion.save
      # acciones para guardado exitoso
    else
      # acciones en caso de error
    end
  end

  private
  def reunion_params
    params.require(:reunion)
          .permit(:planta_id, :centro_costo_id, :producto_id)
          .merge(user_id: current_user.id)
  end
end
```